# How to make jump faster when player is running?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character controller movement where the player can walk, run and jump. However, I facing an issue with the jumping. When jumping while walking, the jump speed looks good. But when jumping while running, the jump speed is too slow compared to the run speed. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera = null;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 3.5f;
    [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] float RunSpeed = 12.0f;
    [SerializeField] float gravity = 9.81f;
    [SerializeField] bool lockCursor = true;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float moveSmoothTime = 0.3f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    Vector3 velocity;
    public float verticalVelocity;
    float cameraPitch = 0.0f;

    CharacterController controller = null;
    Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentDirVelocity = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (lockCursor)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateMouseLook();
        UpdateMovement();
    }
    void UpdateMouseLook()
    {
        Vector2 targetMouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, targetMouseDelta, ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, mouseSmoothTime);

        cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * mouseSensitivity;

        cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        playerCamera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivity);
    }
    void UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector2 targetDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        targetDir.Normalize();

        currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, targetDir, ref currentDirVelocity, moveSmoothTime);

        if (controller.isGrounded)
            velocity.y = 0.0f;
        velocity += (velocity.y < 0 ? Physics.gravity * 2 : Physics.gravity) * Time.deltaTime;

        velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * walkSpeed + Vector3.up * velocity.y;
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J) && controller.isGrounded)
        {
           velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
           velocity += (velocity.y < 0 ? Physics.gravity * 2 : Physics.gravity) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        if ((Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift")) && controller.isGrounded && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * RunSpeed + Vector3.up * velocity.y;
            controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized the above code and removed some dublicate. I also noticed that the speed problem was due to the presence of `isGrounded` in the body of the running condition, which made running dependent on being on the ground. This is the player script:

```cs
   public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera = null;
        [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 3.5f;
        [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 10.0f;
        [SerializeField] float runSpeed = 12.0f;
        [SerializeField] float gravity = 9.81f;
        [SerializeField] bool lockCursor = true;
        [SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float moveSmoothTime = 0.3f;
        public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    
        Vector3 velocity;
        private float verticalVelocity;

        private Vector3 inputVector;
        float cameraPitch = 0.0f;
    
        CharacterController controller = null;
        Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
        Vector3 currentDirVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;

        void Start()
        {
            controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            
            if (lockCursor)
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                Cursor.visible = false;
            }
        }
        void Update()
        {
            UpdateMouseLook();
            UpdateMovement();
        }
        void UpdateMouseLook()
        {
            var targetMouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
    
            currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, targetMouseDelta, ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, moveSmoothTime);
    
            cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * mouseSensitivity;
    
            cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);
    
            playerCamera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;
    
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivity);
        }

        void UpdateMovement()
        {
            // jumping
            var isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1.1f) && velocity.y <= 0;

            if (isGrounded) 
            {
                velocity.y = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) ? Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight) : 0f;
            }
            else
            {
                velocity += (velocity.y < 0 ? Physics.gravity * 2 : Physics.gravity) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            
            controller.Move(velocity);
            
            // movement
            inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;

            var smoothDamp = Vector3.SmoothDamp(inputVector, inputVector, ref currentDirVelocity, moveSmoothTime);

            var runKey = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) &&
                         !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow);

            controller.Move(smoothDamp * (runKey ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Also, these settings were suitable for a height 2 capsule:

[image]

If your character is greater than 2, adjust the length of the ground detection `raycast` accordingly because the `controller.isGrounded` condition does not always work.

[image]

Comment: Now The arrows keys are flipped, the left arrow makes it walks right and so on. and it is not jumping or running anymore.

Comment: Reversing the keys may be due to the camera reversing. If so, one add `-` behind the `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`. I put the jump key in space, ofcourse you can change it manuely, run also has been tested. run works with the right or left shift key.

Comment: for me, the running value was too low that making it not noticeable. when I changed it, it worked. but still not jumping and arrows are flipped I tried this: inputVector = new Vector3(-Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized; but doesn't change anything. I will try to make it work

Comment: I setup script with unity base scale ( as normal like the .gif I uploaded 2 height for character). I think Your project may have larger dimensions and need to be adapted. for flipped axis if `-` it was Ineffective, I really have no idea why the keys were reversed because I tested them and was good. I only know The next step in improving is to add coordination between the keys and the camera, which is done with `Camera.transformDirection`. Of course, this improvement is suitable for 3D games and usually does not require 2D and 2.5D.y, but maybe could, But it may solve the problem of directions.

Comment: thank you so much for your help your effort is appreciated. Can you help me here also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242442/horizontal-mouse-look-is-jittery-and-slow I will accept your answer and vote you up if your answer helped

Comment: @Okashi Mutual thanks friend, I will try and send a message soon.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using character controller you need to do all the calculations for all the situations.
To get the result you are looking for you can do a calculation beetween jump and walking speed.

Another way is to use Rigid body (lock rotations) and add forces for jump and move.

both examples here:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1uoLBp2I1w